# retrieve images from different directory

Tags: laravel, cpanel

I have two laravel projects on the same server connected to the same database on the Cpanel, the first project is the main project and the other one is a subdomain project.
I want to view images for the subdomain project from the images folder in the main project.
I tried to return back to the directory but it didn't work

```
 <img src="{{ url('../images/'.$item->image)}}">
```

however, when I store images from the subdomain project to the images folder in the main project, it works well. but I can't retrieve them back to the view.

Comment: Are both projects Laravel and one is under directory of the other?

Comment: yes @SebastianSulinski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - so here's what you could do to make it work.

If you don't have already, create your own helpers file and add it to composer's autoload:

**app/helpers.php**

```php
<?php

if (! function_exists('parentAsset')) {
    /**
     * Generate a parentAsset path for the application.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @param  bool|null  $secure
     * @return string
     */
    function parentAsset($path, $secure = null)
    {
        return app('parentUrl')->asset($path, $secure);
    }
}
```

**composer.json**

```json
{
    //...
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    //...
}
```

Register `parentUrl` in the container

**app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php**

```php
use Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator;

public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton('parentUrl', function ($app) {
        $routes = $app['router']->getRoutes();

        $app->instance('routes', $routes);

        return new UrlGenerator(
            $routes,
            $app->rebinding('request', $this->requestRebinder()),
            $app['config']['app.parent_asset_url']
        );
    });
}

/**
 * Get the URL generator request rebinder.
 *
 * @return \Closure
 */
protected function requestRebinder()
{
    return function ($app, $request) {
        $app['url']->setRequest($request);
    };
}
```

Please note the new config entry for `app` namespace: `parent_asset_url`. You now need to add it to your `app.php` config file.

**config/app.php**

```php
[

    //...
    'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', null),
    'parent_asset_url' => env('PARENT_ASSET_URL', null),
    //...

]
```

Lastly you need to add `PARENT_ASSET_URL` variable to your `.env` file and specify the url of your parent application.

```
PARENT_ASSET_URL=https://google.com
```

Recompile autoloader

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

And you can now use the `parentAsset` helper to load files directly from the parent domain:

```
<img src="{{ parentAsset('/assets/images/logo.svg') }}">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm working on the cPanel how can I write this command?
composer dump-autoload -o @sebastian

Comment: You need to make all these changes locally, then deploy / upload your code back to the server. Are you using git repository or just ftp upload?

Comment: Also - if you're purely relying on cPanel - here's how you can access terminal via panel - which is where you'd run this command once you're in the projects directory: https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/enable-terminal-application-for-cpanel/

Comment: okay. one other thing, In which project should I make all these updates, in the main project, the subdomain project or both?

Comment: It's supposed to be a sub domain one, but it depends on which one you want to access the other one from - you can apply it to both and have option to access both sites resources.